# Permission denied error while running a code on google cloud ML

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I am getting an error while trying to read a file within the code.

File isn't open for reading") PermissionDeniedError: File isn't open for reading

file is located within the trainer folder on the google cloud shell. This is what I have given to read the file with file_io.FileIO('/home/arpit_agrawal/DeepSpeech/trainer/data/‌​spell/words.txt','r+‌​') as f: WORDS = set(words(f.read()))

THIS WAS THE ERROR IN LOG FILES : WORDS = set(words(f.read())) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/‌​lib/io/file_io.py", line 106, in read self._preread_check() File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/‌​lib/io/file_io.py", line 70, in _preread_check "File isn't open for reading") PermissionDeniedError: File isn't open for reading

result of ls -la for words.txt

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 arpit_agrawal arpit_agrawal 12124743 Apr 11 17:53 words.txt
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code you are using to read the file. Is the file located on GCS or the local filesystem? Are you running locally or using the CMLE service?

Comment: file is located within the trainer folder on the google cloud shell. This is what I have given to read the file 
with file_io.FileIO('/home/arpit_agrawal/DeepSpeech/trainer/data/spell/words.txt','r+') as f:
    WORDS = set(words(f.read()))

Comment: THIS WAS THE ERROR IN LOG FILES :<module> WORDS = set(words(f.read())) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 106, in read self._preread_check() File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 70, in _preread_check "File isn't open for reading") PermissionDeniedError: File isn't open for reading

Comment: @Appu: At the bottom of your question, there's an "edit" link that is crying out for you to click on it. :-)

Comment: The code looks correct.  Does the file exist and what are the permissions? Can you do an ls -la /home/arpit_agrawal/DeepSpeech/trainer/data/‌​spell/words.txt and paste the output into the original question? Are you running inside Cloud Shell?

Comment: Yes, i am running inside Cloud Shell

Comment: result of ls -la for words.txt

    -rwxr-xr-x 1 arpit_agrawal arpit_agrawal 12124743 Apr 11 17:53 words.txt

Comment: What happens if you try to read using Python file operations as opposed to TensorFlow functions?

Comment: It gives an error no such file or directory found

Comment: @Appu You said you are running inside Cloud Shell. But I noticed that the stack trace shows the file location of file_io.py is '/root/.local/...". In Cloud Shell, that location is '/usr/local/lib/...'. It sounds like what you're running from Cloud Shell is `gcloud ml-engine jobs`, but the jobs itself is being submitted and run on the service. Is that correct? If so, then the root cause of the problem is you need to place your data files not on cloud shell but on GCS.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is a unicode issue in the code you pasted. Specifically there are non printable unicode characters there. I copied and pasted from the code you wrote and ran the following.

```
In [2]: 'r+‌​'=='r+'
Out[2]: False
```

The left one was copied from the original stackoverflow post. I'd suggest deleting that code and retyping it.